# What is an easy way to replace duplicated object serialisations by the ID in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a nested data structure, where somewhere down the hierarchy the same objects are used several times. What I want as a result is, that when serializing this via Jackson, it is somehow detected than an object has already been written to the output and instead of serializing the object again, its ID is used.

Is Jackson able to do this for me, or do I have to implement this manually?

Example:

```
AddressBook
  |
  Person
    |
    Tag
```

A lot of Persons can have the same Tag. I only want each Tag object once in the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty trivial to implement manually - just have a `HashSet` containing all the `Tag` objects. Then, as you're serializing, if an object's tag is already contained in the set, you know it's already been serialized.